# java List type variable

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have been breaking my head with below code which I made. The problem is that when I do 
tail.child = null;
it is also making my childPoint's child as null.
tail is instance variable with below definition:

```
public List tail;
public void removeMultiLinkList() {
    List headPoint = head;
    while (headPoint.next != null) {
        List childPoint = headPoint;
        while (childPoint.child != null) {
            tail.next = childPoint.child;
            tail = tail.next;
            tail.child=null;
            childPoint = childPoint.child;
        }
        headPoint = headPoint.next;
    }
}
```

I have made this method to solve the problem of multilevel link list and convert it into linear singly link by in non recurssive manner

Comment: By @Jeremy : Can you show us the `List` class you are using?

Comment: Also, I assume `head` is also an instance variable?

Answer (score 2):

Examine what you are doing:

```
tail.next = childPoint.child; 
tail = tail.next;
```

In here, `tail` is `childPoint.child` (reference identity)

Then, you do:

```
tail.child=null;
```

This means, you actually set `childPoint.child.child = null;` - because `chilePoint.child` and `tail` are different names for the same object.

And then, you assign:

```
childPoint = childPoint.child;
```

But you assign childPoint to the same object you just changed - so the new `childPoint`'s `child`, is `null`!

---

A very easy workaround is to copy by value (by creating a copy constructor) the elements from one list to the other.

An alternative might be to keep copying references - but without changing `child` at all. At the end of your algorithm, do some post-processing and set `e.child = null` for each element `e` in your list.